# How to get URL in active tab and use it in variable

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to get url for use it in variable with an chrome extension.
I read here this code :

```
   chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    var tabURL = tabs[0].url;
    console.log(tabURL);
});
```

but it doesn't work on this url

```
http://sail.zezo.org/clipperton-noumea/chart.pl?lat=-15.93361&lon=-176.0022&userid=1577252
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Route zezo.org",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Extraire la route proposée",
  "permissions": [
    "http://sail.zezo.org/*",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "icons": {    
        "16": "icon-16.png",
        "48": "icon-48.png",
        "128": "icon-128.png"
  },    
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }  
}
```

I don't understand where I make a mistake ...

(Sorry for my bad English ...)

Comment: Rightclick the popup, then `Inspect` and you'll see the console. Also, make sure to use the variable only inside the callback as chrome.* API is asynchronous.

Comment: @wOxxOm

Ok thanks, I didn't now rightclik -> Inspect ...
It works fine ;)
But if I want to exploit the variable tabURL after ?
I need to link var url of the script popup.js to var tabURL of the script background.js

Comment: You want to pass your variable to background page ? You need to use message passing : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Comment: No, I want to pass the variable in background.js to popup.js
But it's the same I think

Comment: Perhaps with chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()
I have only this in my background.js
`chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    var tabURL = tabs[0].url;
});`

Comment: `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bkgd));
var url = bkgd.tabURL;
console.log(url);`
No work ... :/

Comment: @GeGaX In background.js page try to set the tabUrRL variable outside the function . I mean : var tabURL="";
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {  tabURL = tabs[0].url; }); and then to use chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage .

Comment: @OriEng : For background.js: `var tabURL = ""; chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) { tabURL = tabs[0].url; });` It's ok I have the good url. For popup.js: `var url = "" chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPage){ url = backgroundPage.tabURL; });` And ... no ... Don't work, I don't understand :( Where I make a mistake ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so I write you the full solution to get the the active url in popup.js:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Route zezo.org",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Extraire la route proposée",
  "permissions": [
  "http://sail.zezo.org/*",
  "tabs"
   ],
   "content_scripts": [
    {
     "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
     "js": ["content.js"],
     "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
   "icons": {    
      "16": "icon-16.png",
      "48": "icon-48.png",
      "128": "icon-128.png"
       },    
   "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
   "background": {
     "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }

}
```

popup.js

```
window.onload=function(){
  chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(backgroundPage){ 
  var currentUrl = backgroundPage.tabURL;
  //Use the url ........
  console.log(currentUrl);

 })

};
```

background.js

```
var tabURL = ""; 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(message, sender, sendResponse) {

   chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, 
     function(arrayOfTabs) {
       var activeTab = arrayOfTabs[0];
       tabURL = activeTab.url;

     });
    }
  );
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("send");
```

The idea: your extension is run in any url you put in *'matches'*  in your manifest. The content script send message to background page that you want to get this url , the background page get the message and set it in the variable and then you take this variable in your popup.js page . now you could do whatever you want with this variable .

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot !
I test this tonight ;)

Comment: It's works perfectly ;)) Thanks again OriEng, one question ... it's a "generic" code ? I can use it for all ( get url ) ?

Comment: @GeGaX Happy to help ! What you mean by "generic" in this case ? It's work for every url right now but you could change it simply by changing the 'matches' in your manifest .

Comment: 'Generic' in the sense that the code doesn't change, it can be applied everywhere (I keep it under the elbow thank you again) ;)